# What is "singleton set" in Chinese?

Tags: translation, terminology

In set theory, a **singleton set** is a set with just one element.

The term is not in any of my dictionaries, and the only online source I found is [one page of zh.wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%97%AD%E9%9B%86) which just transliterates it as 辛格尔顿.  A search on line shows this is hardly ever used.

A friend who is not a set theorist suggests 单元 for singleton.  I wonder what Chinese set theorists usually use.

Comment: How about `单元素集（合）`?

Comment: @songyuanyao Both Baidu and my friend go with 单元集合, but Zh.wikipedia does not.   Can you recommend some set theory book in Chinese on line to look at?

Comment: You won't find the technical term in any normal dictionaries. You might need to check the corresponding textbook in Chinese version(normally will be a university textbook if it comes to set theory). Or try to look it up in special dictionaries which focus in the specific area.

Comment: A tactic I commonly use is to find the term on Wikipedia, and then look for the Chinese-language version.  Not infallible, but often a good start.  In this case, it yields [單元素集合](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E5%8D%95%E5%85%83%E7%B4%A0%E9%9B%86%E5%90%88).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

单元素集合 is the correct and exact word for singleton set in Chinese, confirmed by a Chinese friend of my who is a mathematician.

There is a Baidu encyclopaedia entry for [单元素集合](http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=Y8jBc-KXbrhnzdeEEu-wG2nv8EGAvF2iI6jSpQOBQsaw_yka3gh74RHw0O_Z7Uhj7d138noht8m6TRTP2HLXkOkHsWz7KFvUUmR5aSAD2NnYOwrQTLyPLR77Y3KbelKtkVxcOR8DAftDUo9OnAQK-a), where it is defined as "由唯一一个元素组成的集合", i.e. a set containing a single element, followed by an example {0}.